# Unable to set position of Html Table using PptxGenJs library

Tags: qlikview, pptxgenjs

Need Help,I'm using PptxGen to create PowerPoint reports of HTML. I'm using function addSlidesForTable to pass HTML table id, also I have requirement to each slide provide  title with one straight line and after that Html table but Table position has not affecting any changes in ppt slides.

pptx=new PptxGenJS();

```
    pptx.setLayout('LAYOUT_WIDE');
    pptx.defineSlideMaster({
      title: 'MASTER_SLIDE',
      bkgd:  'FFFFFF',
      objects: [
        { 'line':  { x: 0.5, y:0.0, w:12.00, line:'0088CC', lineSize:0.2,flipH:true,rotate:4.7 } },
        { 'line':  { x: 0.5, y:6.0, w:12.00, line:'0088CC', lineSize:0.2,flipH:true,rotate:4.7 } },
        { 'text':  { text:'Tabular Report', options:{ x:0.4, y:0.15, w:5.5, h:0.06, fontFace:'Arial',fontSize:20,color:'0088CC' } } }
      ],
      slideNumber: { x:0.5, y:'95%', fontFace:'Arial',fontSize:8 }
    }); 

    var slide = pptx.addNewSlide('MASTER_SLIDE');
    pptx.addSlidesForTable("tabAutoPaging1",{addHeaderToEach:true,master:'MASTER_SLIDE',options:{x:0.5, y:3.5} })

    pptx.save('Sample Presentation');
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide x and y positions without the options parameter.

Your addSlidesForTable method call should be like

```
pptx.addSlidesForTable("tabAutoPaging1",{addHeaderToEach:true,master:'MASTER_SLIDE', x:0.5, y:3.5} })
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for comments. However , I figure out the solution for this problem.we need to add margin:{0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5} properties in master slide object and I checked it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

pptx.setLayout('LAYOUT_WIDE');
    pptx.defineSlideMaster({
      title: 'MASTER_SLIDE',
      bkgd:  'FFFFFF',
     margin:[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],
      objects: [
        { 'line':  { x: 0.5, y:0.0, w:12.00, line:'0088CC', lineSize:0.2,flipH:true,rotate:4.7 } },
        { 'line':  { x: 0.5, y:6.0, w:12.00, line:'0088CC', lineSize:0.2,flipH:true,rotate:4.7 } },
        { 'text':  { text:'Tabular Report', options:{ x:0.4, y:0.15, w:5.5, h:0.06, fontFace:'Arial',fontSize:20,color:'0088CC' } } }
      ],
      slideNumber: { x:0.5, y:'95%', fontFace:'Arial',fontSize:8 }
    });

```
var slide = pptx.addNewSlide('MASTER_SLIDE');
pptx.addSlidesForTable("tabAutoPaging1",{addHeaderToEach:true,master:'MASTER_SLIDE',options:{x:0.5, y:3.5} })

pptx.save('Sample Presentation');
```